# Does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this query in making my view but the problem is this view is not included in my Model. So, I could not use this view.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Payment_Transaction_vw]
AS 
    SELECT 
        id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
        Transaction_Info.trans_name, Student_Info.ID_Number,
        Student_Info.student_fname, Student_Info.student_lname,
        SUM(Payment_Transaction.amount) AS amount
    FROM 
        [Payment_Transaction]
    INNER JOIN 
        Student_Info ON Payment_Transaction.student_info_id = Student_Info.student_info_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        Transaction_Info ON Payment_Transaction.trans_info_id = Transaction_Info.trans_info_id 
    GROUP BY 
        ID_Number, student_lname, student_fname, trans_name;
```

This view can be seen in the database after I create this. But not when I add a model. This is not included in my Entity.

Here is the error will displayed:

> dbo.Payment_Transaction_vw does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review our schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.

Please help me with this matter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it might be because EF has a hard time choosing the correct primary key. A way to force EF to choose a key of your liking seems to be to use `ISNULL()` for the primary key, and `NULLIF()` for the other columns (at least the ones that could cause confusion, like primary keys from other tables or non-nullable columns).

In your case this would mean:

```sql
SELECT 
    ISNULL(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), -1) AS Id,
    NULLIF(Transaction_Info.trans_name,'') AS trans_name, 
    NULLIF(Student_Info.ID_Number,-1) AS ID_Number,
    NULLIF(Student_Info.student_fname,'') AS student_fname, 
    NULLIF(Student_Info.student_lname,'') AS student_lname,
    NULLIF(SUM(Payment_Transaction.amount),-1) AS amount
FROM [Payment_Transaction]
INNER JOIN Student_Info ON 
    Payment_Transaction.student_info_id = Student_Info.student_info_id 
INNER JOIN Transaction_Info ON 
    Payment_Transaction.trans_info_id = Transaction_Info.trans_info_id 
GROUP BY ID_Number, student_lname, student_fname, trans_name;
```

You probably don't need all these `NULLIF()`'s, but since I'm not sure what column is causing issues it's better to take all. If it works with this code, you can start removing the NULLIF from *student names* and *trans_name*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define first id column primary key mvc does not allow this when you are using it with model

Comment: How will I implement it?

Comment: when you create table assign it

Comment: All of my table has a primary key

Comment: this kind of error occur only then when you did not assign primary key

Comment: I only got this error after I created a view with my script above but my tables don't have this error cuz I have assigned all with a primary key